# Android GUI refresh (no threads used)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, fragment

I have an activity with an AutoCompleteTextView (text).

When i select an item the code below is executed:

```
 text.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Bundle args= new Bundle();

            for (Student s: studentsBook.getStudentsList()){

                if (s.getName().equals(((TextView)view).getText().toString())){

                    args.putSerializable("Student",s);
                    break;
                }
            }

            theLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //removing elements (button, textviews...) 
            addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); //removing elements

            //simply adding a fragment through supportfragmentmanager and fragment transactions
//Fragment receives arguments (args) which contain a string to be showed.
//A tag: "DataFragment" is provided in order to get the fragment back in other parts of code.
//getMainView returns the container in which the fragment has to be created/showed.
            dataFragment=(StudentDataFragment)addFragment(StudentDataFragment.class,R.layout.student_data_fragment,getMainView().getId(),args,"DataFragment");
        }
    });
```

The fragment has only this method:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myLayout=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_data_fragment,container,false);

    student=(Student)getArguments().getSerializable("Student");
    tv=((TextView)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView17));
    tv.setText(student.toString());
    return myLayout;
}
```

I can't see the string, it seems that the gui gets not updated, but if an orientation change happens the string appears..

I also managed the back button to remove the fragment if present and set visible the elements "gone". The code runs successfully but no gui refresh appears to be run.

No threads are involved in this situation, so i think we are in the UI-thread right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just messing up the content view of the activity in other parts of code